# quadtree for point data in 2D space in matlab

Tags: matlab, quadtree

Let's say: I have the point data in 2D space:

```
A=[x1 y1         %point 1
   x2 y2         %point 2
   x3 y3         %point 3
  .......
   x100 y100]    %point 100
```

Do you have any code to use a quadtree for that data in Matlab? (I tried to search on Google, but all results shown the code for image(picture) only.

Thanks,

Comment: Search octree+quadtree

Comment: ok. finally I found the code